# SCIP 3.2.0 doesn't replace message handler

Tags: scip, output-redirect, message-handlers

I want the SCIP callable to print all messages to stderr (using it as a flatzinc solver). I've tried

```
SCIP_DECL_MESSAGEWARNING(printMsg) {
  cerr << msg << flush;
}
...
      SCIP_MESSAGEHDLR* pHndl=0;
      SCIP_CALL ( SCIPmessagehdlrCreate ( &pHndl, FALSE, NULL, FALSE, printMsg, printMsg, printMsg, NULL, NULL) );
```

without effect...

Answer (score 1):

Try alse making SCIP aware of your message handler:

```
  SCIP_CALL( SCIPsetMessagehdlr(scip, pHndl) );
```

This will make SCIP also capture your message handler, so if you don't need it anymore, you can release it:

```
  SCIP_CALL( SCIPmessagehdlrRelease(&pHndl) );
```

This will not overwrite the handler for error messages, as these might have to be printed when no SCIP is around yet. You can set a handler for this one via SCIPmessageSetErrorPrinting(). But they already go to stderr.

Comment: Would be helpful to add this to the description of SCIPmessagehdlrCreate because now it only says it also captures the created handle